# Latlon coordinates from Brazil postalcode

Tags: geopy

I have been trying to get the latlon coordinates from Brazil postalcode without success. The piece of code I am using is bellow:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
geolocator.geocode({"postalcode": 14160-570, "countryRegion":"Brazil"})
```

I am getting NoneType. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Documentation under https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim does not seem to suggest to me that `postalcode` could be such an “interval” (and it doesn’t even mention `countryRegion` parameter there.) So where from did you take that this was supposed to work this way?

Comment: Thank you for engage! I take that syntax from here: https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/333#event-1959489629

Comment: That is from the `bing.py` example, so it is likely Bing specific. If you check the actual [example file provided for nominatim](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/e2039effe647f6bb4095baa98e3f46c631197746/test/geocoders/nominatim.py) however - no such thing in there …